# What is the difference between getDir and getFilesDir on Android?

Tags: android, file, private

I would like to save a picture in Internal Storage of my app, to make it private. So I did a little research and saw 2 ways to get the directory.

1.With [getDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) :

```
File dir = getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2.With [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) :

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
```

Which is best ? Which returns the location in Internal Storage ?

The way of writing files depends on the way you get your dir ? I am a bit lost since there are many ways to write files in Android.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`getFilesDir()` returns a File object to a directory that is private to your application only. When you use `openFileOutput(String, int)`, the data you write is directly stored in this directory and is not accessible by any other application. It holds your application files.

`getDir()` enables you to create any file or directory in the internal memory, which is also accessible by other applications depending on the mode you create it. `openFileOutput(String, int)` will not work with the output of this so you will have to use other means of writing and reading files to deal with this directory or file. This is more used for creating custom files other than files only used by your application.

Comment: Thanks ! And does `File dir = getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` will get me a `File` in the internal memory (because of `MODE_PRIVATE`) ?

Comment: You are welcome. MODE_PRIVATE is the default constant for getDir and it says your file/directory will be private to your application. getDir will always return/create an internal directory. Watch out for the fact that DIRECTORY_PICTURES is for API 8 and up.

Comment: @Erol So can I conclude that getDir with `MODE_PRIVATE` is same as the getFilesDir in some way...?