# Android getFilesDir() vs getDir() - What do I use to save files in my apps private data?

Tags: java, android

I understand this question is very similar: [What is the difference between getDir and getFilesDir on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781260/what-is-the-difference-between-getdir-and-getfilesdir-on-android)

But, I'm still not sure what to use when I simply want to save my files in my private data.

For a directory should I just use `data/data/com.test.myapp`? That will make it private to my application?

```
// Gets the absolute path to the filesystem directory where your internal files are saved.
getFilesDir()

// Creates (or opens an existing) directory within your internal storage space.
getDir()
```

I've also tried reading through some of the commonsware open source projects, but I guess I just get even more confused about the whole `getExternalFilesDir()` because doesn't Android refer to internal storage (non-sdcard) as "external" storage after a certain api level?

Comment: getFilesDir() is essentially getDir("files").  It's a fine place to put app-private data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm still not sure what to use when I simply want to save my files in my private data

`getFilesDir()` will work nicely.

> For a directory should I just use data/data/com.test.myapp?

Never hardcode directories.

> That will make it private to my application?

`getFilesDir()` is private to your application (exception: users who have rooted their devices and run apps with superuser privileges)

I do not know of any really good use for `getDir()`, and I do not recommend it.

> because doesn't Android refer to internal storage (non-sdcard) as "external" storage after a certain api level?

External storage has existed since before Android 1.0.

Internal storage roughly means "private to your app" (unless you take specific steps to make it non-private). External storage roughly means "visible to the user and to other apps".

In [a book that I know that you own](http://commonsware.com/Android) :-), you will find more details about internal and external storage in the "Assets, Files, and Data Parsing" chapter.

Comment: Clear and concise. As always. Thanks again. Also, best book I've ever purchased =)

Comment: +1, but it would be a good idea to mention that you should never hardcode directories because different android devices/versions of android put files in different places.  This is especially gnarly because it might work on whatever device you're testing on, just to break the moment you try it on a different phone.

Comment: @Prime: While `/data/data/your.package.name/` is generally what is used, it is certainly possible for devices to do something odd. Also, Android 4.2+ will use a different location for secondary accounts on tablets. `getFilesDir()` eliminates those problems, and is shorter to boot. :-)